# why i am getting 404 page not found instead of 200

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, spring-security-oauth2

I am performing Junit test of an endpoint which is secured by oauth2, token is getting generated but the get request to the endpoint is coming as 404 not found. Please look into the screenshots of the problem.

```
https://github.com/aki59/petCare/issues/5#issue-473461121
```

I have already tried @TestConfiguration annotation on the controller class as i am using spring boot 2.1.6 but not luck.

```
Test class :-

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes=AuthServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {

     @Autowired
     private WebApplicationContext wac;

     @Autowired
     private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

     @Autowired
     private UserController accountController;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "inventory-service";

     @Before
     public void setup() {
      this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
        }

    @Test
    public void shouldGive200_status()throws Exception {
        String accessToken = obtainAccessToken("akash69tiwari@gmail.com", "password");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/uaa/user/current").header("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

Controller class:-

@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final Logger LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";


     @RequestMapping(value="user/current",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public Principal getUser(Principal principal) {
            return principal;
        }

I have tried the same thing with postman and it is working just fine.
```

Comment: why do you have this additionally `/uaa`?

Comment: There is a mismatch in your request mapping and mock call url. Please check it.

Comment: and also try this https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: hi @Deadpool "/uaa" i have put beacuse my context path includes that also but removing that also i am getting the same warning of page not found